# how to prove ‘¬∃xP(x)→(P(a)→Q(a))’ from no premises? fitch

Tags: logic, fitch

I am totally lost on how to do this... can anyone help?

What does it mean? I tried to understand what it means before proof but am totally clueless

Comment: Assume the antecedent and assume **Pa**. From it, by exists-intro, derive a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

> > ¬∃xP(x)→(P(a)→Q(a))
>
> What does it mean? I tried to understand what it means before proof but am totally clueless

It says: `P(a)→Q(a)` is true, *if* `P(x)` holds for no `x`.

So why would `P(a)→Q(a)` be true when *that* is assumed?

Answer (score -2):

@GrahamKemp is correct. The statement says that if P(x) holds for no member of the universe of discourse, then P(a)->Q(a).

Recall that the truth table for the material conditional informs us that a material conditional statement is true when the antecedent is false.

So the proof is relatively easy:
[image]